# Does a strictly increasing continuous function map a measure zero set to a measure zero set?

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, lebesgue-measure, monotone-functions

The following is a theorem from Bruckner's Real Analysis:

[image]

A function $F$ satisfies Lusin’s condition (N) means that if $λ(B) = 0$ then $λ(f(B)) = 0$. This is proven for an absolutely continuous function. Even though the theorem is about an absolutely continuous function but first it supposes for a strictly increasing continuous function and claims that still satisfies Lusin’s condition (N).

My question is : Does a strictly increasing continuous function satisfy Lusin’s condition (N)? If not, then the proof is wrong and how to modify it?

**Added :** Is this approach possible? Let $F$ be absolutely continuous and be written as $G-H$ (both strictly increasing, none necessarily absolutely continuous). Then $F(b)-F(a)=(G-H)(b)-(G-H)(a)=\int_a^b G' dλ - \int_a^b H' dλ + λ(G(B))-λ(H(B))$. The proof is complete by showing that $λ(G(B))-λ(H(B))$ is zero. Loosely speaking, $λ(F(B))=λ(G(B)-H(B))=0$ so $G(B)-H(B)$ has measure zero the difference between $λ(G(B))$ and $λ(H(B))$ can be made arbitrarily small. If I am right how can I make this a rigorous one?

Comment: The answer is no, for example the Cantor function. So the proof of Theorem 7.18 is wrong!

Comment: Technically speaking the Cantor function is not strictly increasing. But $x$ + Cantor Function(x) would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

1. You ask: "Does a strictly increasing continuous function satisfy Lusin’s condition (N)?" . The answer is NO. A counter-example would be $f: [0,1] \to [0,2]$ defined by $f(x)= x+ g(x)$, where $g$ is the Cantor function (but, such function $f$ is not absolutely continuous).
2. Is the proof of the Theorem 7.18 wrong? The answer is NO.  In the first part , $F$ is supposed to be absolutely continuous **and** strictly increasing (not only strictly increasing).
   In the second part of the proof, it is explicitly used the fact that any absolutely continuous function $F$ can be written as $F= G-H$, where $G$ and $H$ are absolutely continuous strictly increasing functions. And proving such result is the content of Exercise 7:5.2.

Comment: I don't think the proof is assuming absolutely continuous and strictly increasing together (Please see Theorem 3.8. at whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/grady.pdf). Unless there would be a theorem stating "**Any** absolutely continuous function can be written as the difference of two increasing, **absolutely** continuous functions (?)

Comment: @L.G.  1. $F$ is assumed to be absolutely continuous  all the time during the proof. In the first part, it is **also** assumed to be strictly increasing. 2. Yes, any absolutely continuous function can be written as the difference of two increasing, absolutely continuous functions. This is explicitly stated in beginning of the second part of the proof ("In the general case,... ) and you are asked to prove it as **Exercise 7:5.2**.

Comment: @L.G. The conclusion of Theorem  3.8. at whitman.edu/Documents/Academics/Mathematics/grady.pdf can be improved to "$f$ can  be written as the difference of two increasing, *absolutely* continuous functions".  To prove this "improved version" is exactly Exercise 7:5.2.

Comment: Neither could I prove nor find a proof for the claim of the Ex-7:5.2!

Comment: @L.G. See Real Analysis - Royden, Fitzpatrick (4th ed) - Chapter 6, Theorem 8.

Comment: @L.G. Please not that $F(B)= (G-H)(B) \neq G(B)-H(B)$. So, in principle, $\lambda(F(B)) \neq \lambda(G(B)-H(B))$.

Comment: That's the definition if difference of two functions (?) (G−H)(x)=G(x)−H(x) for each x, so (G−H)(B)=G(B)−H(B) (?)

Comment: @L.G. , $G(B)$ and $H(B)$ are sets, not functions, so what do you mean by $G(B)- H(B)$ ?  
Typically $G(B)- H(B)= \{ y_1-y_2 : y_1 \in G(B) \text{ and } y_2 \in H(B) \}$  which is different from 
$(G-H)(B) = \{ G(x)-H(x) : x \in B\}$.